# I am having trouble with shifting my car in the correct gear

Tags: automatic-transmission, shifting, gears

I would like to know what’s wrong with my car .. why does it drives in neutral??I have a 2008 Ford Focus and my shift gear doesn’t drive on the DRIVE label nor park on the Park label .. i don’t know what’s wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the linkage has slipped.

You should get this looked at and corrected before you loose access to reverse and get stuck somewhere, since it has slipped already, then it will do so again before long.